# What event/interface is used to show the IWebBrowser2 secure warning?

Tags: com, winapi, interface, iwebbrowser2

I am using a IWebBrowser2 control in my application and writing my own container (in C++ - No ATL/MFC allowed).  The control works fine.  However web sites will not show if I am going from secure to non secure.  It trails back to the setting in advanced options of IE (WarnonZoneCrossing) : Warn if changing between secure and not secure.  It works without this checked.

When doing this within the actual IE browser, it will show a messagebox to ask the user.  I am fine also showing the user this box.  My question would be what interface or event could I be missing that makes this message box not appear and the web page rendering stall?

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake on my part.  I had it in silent mode.  Apparently in silent mode when you have that dialog pop up and it can not be answered, it will show a blank page (makes sense, but confuses me :)).  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but have you tried implementing [IDocHostUIHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753260(VS.85).aspx)::[ShowUI()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753265(VS.85).aspx)?

Failing that, have a look at interfaces that the WebOC is asking for via QueryInterface() and IServiceProvider::QueryService() and see if any make sense in this case.